Query to find position in a string before keyword and extract data before that position
Our data is in a SQL Server 2022 (v16.0.1000.6) database. I'm using SSMS v20.2.
When a person makes a change to a record, that change is captured in a log table as a string column called LogText. Each time a change is made, the change is appended to this column. The date of the change is captured in a different column.
My problem is trying to parse out the most current change which would be at the end of the string in the LogText column. The following is an example of an inventory record for a part. The DemandQty and OnHandQty have been changed numerous times with the most current changes at the end of the string. I'm thinking that I'd need to start at the end of the string, find the first occurrence of DemandQty and extract the value after the -> characters. Same with OnHandQty.
My question is twofold:

How do I find the position of -> that comes before DemandQty or OnHandQty in the reversed string?
How do I extract the integer value before the arrow in the reversed string?

Example string:
12:01:07  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  12:01:07  OnHandQty: 9743.00000000 -> 10000.00000000  15:24:25  DemandQty: 0 -> 257.00000000  15:31:09  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  15:31:09  DemandQty: 257.00000000 -> 127.00000000

Expected result: DemandQty = 127, OnHandQty = 9743
Actual result:  NULL
This is what I've come up with for the DemandQty, however the @arrowPos variable is returning the position of <- (in the reversed string) AFTER the first DemandQty rather than before.
DECLARE @inputString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '12:01:07  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  12:01:07  OnHandQty: 9743.00000000 -> 10000.00000000  15:24:25  DemandQty: 0 -> 257.00000000  15:31:09  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  15:31:09  DemandQty: 257.00000000 -> 127.00000000'
 
-- Reverse the input string to find the last occurrence of 'DemandQty' from the end.
DECLARE @reversedString NVARCHAR(MAX) = REVERSE(@inputString);
 
-- Find the position of the first 'DemandQty' in the reversed string.
DECLARE @demandQtyPos INT = CHARINDEX('ytqdnamed', @reversedString) - 1;  -- 'ytqdnamed' is 'DemandQty' reversed.
 
-- Find the position of the '>-' symbol that comes before the first 'DemandQty' in the reversed string.
DECLARE @arrowPos INT = CHARINDEX('>-', @reversedString, @demandQtyPos);
 
-- Extract the value after '>-' and the space.
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(50) = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @arrowPos > 0 THEN
            -- Extract the substring after '>-' (ignoring the space), and reverse it back to get the correct order.
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@reversedString, @arrowPos + 2, CHARINDEX(' ', @reversedString + ' ', @arrowPos + 2) - @arrowPos - 2))
        ELSE 
            NULL
    END;

------Convert the extracted value to an integer.
SELECT CAST(@result AS INT) AS ExtractedIntegerValue; 


Honestly, it seems like it would be better™ to have whatever is sending this data to SQL Server to normalise it first and then store it in a normalised format in SQL Server. The data should not be getting to your data engine in the condition it's in. I really recommend you fix your design first. T-SQL is not an ideal language for handling this.

Thanks @ThomA.  This is not an option.  The database is not my design and is native to the ERP we use so I'm stuck with what it is. I don't like the way it maintains history but this is what I've got to work with.

Think for a while what would be a reverse of ->, spoiler alert, it ain't <-

@siggemannen, you are absolutely correct, reversed it would be >-.  I made that change in my query but am still not getting the result I expect.  The arrowPos is returning 66 which means that part of my query is looking for the >- AFTER the first instance of DemandQty rather than before it.

I edited my original post to show that change.  I also realized the last part of my attempted solution didn't get pasted into the original post so added that as well.

I'd probably get the string after the last OnHand string and then parse the needed pieces out one by one, this is very basic stuff. STUFF function is very handy for this, and RIGHT

While I'm not new to SQL, I'm fairly new to SQL development so this is a struggle for me.  I'm hoping to write a function I can use to extract this data in a query.  I'm not familiar with STUFF. Could you provide an example of how I could use this?  I'd still need to find the last occurrence of OnHandQty to parse out everything after that.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Side note, Version 16.0.1000.6 is the RTM release of SQL Server 2022; not installing any security updates for 2 years is a serious failing. I strongly suggest you get your instance updated.

I would, honestly, make best attempts to normalise your data, and then work with that data. This makes best attempts to do so, and works for the data you have. Most likely you then want a Top 1 in each group in that result set.
DECLARE @YourString varchar(8000) = '12:01:07  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  12:01:07  OnHandQty: 9743.00000000 -> 10000.00000000  15:24:25  DemandQty: 0 -> 257.00000000  15:31:09  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  15:31:09  DemandQty: 257.00000000 -> 127.00000000';

WITH Split AS(
    SELECT TRIM(SS.value) AS value,
           SS.ordinal,
           (ss.ordinal+1) / 2 AS item
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@YourString,'  ','|'),'|',1) SS),
Pivoted AS(
    SELECT S.item,
           MAX(CASE WHEN S.value LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' THEN S.value END) AS EventTime,
           MAX(CASE WHEN S.value NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' THEN S.value END) AS EventValue
    FROM Split S
    GROUP BY S.item) --Will also need to group on a unique value if this is coming from a table, not a variable
SELECT P.EventTime,
       V.EventName,
       MAX(CASE SS.ordinal WHEN 1 THEN TRIM(SS.value) END) AS FromValue,
       MAX(CASE SS.ordinal WHEN 2 THEN TRIM(SS.value) END) AS ToValue
FROM Pivoted P  
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',P.EventValue),0)))CI(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEFT(P.EventValue,CI.I-1),TRIM(STUFF(P.EventValue,1,CI.I,''))))V(EventName,EventValue)
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(V.EventValue,'->','|'),'|',1) SS
GROUP BY P.EventTime,
         P.item,
         V.EventName;--Will also need to group on a unique value if this is coming from a table, not a variable

And, as mentioned, if you needed to do a get the "last" values:
WITH Split AS(
    SELECT TRIM(SS.value) AS value,
           SS.ordinal,
           (ss.ordinal+1) / 2 AS item
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@YourString,'  ','|'),'|',1) SS),
Pivoted AS(
    SELECT S.item,
           MAX(CASE WHEN S.value LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' THEN S.value END) AS EventTime,
           MAX(CASE WHEN S.value NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' THEN S.value END) AS EventValue
    FROM Split S
    GROUP BY S.item), --Will also need to group on a unique value if this is coming from a table, not a variable
RNs AS(
    SELECT P.EventTime,
           V.EventName,
           MAX(CASE SS.ordinal WHEN 1 THEN TRIM(SS.value) END) AS FromValue,
           MAX(CASE SS.ordinal WHEN 2 THEN TRIM(SS.value) END) AS ToValue,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.EventName ORDER BY P.EventTime DESC, P.item DESC) AS RN --May need to aklter PARTITION BY is using a column
    FROM Pivoted P  
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',P.EventValue),0)))CI(I)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEFT(P.EventValue,CI.I-1),TRIM(STUFF(P.EventValue,1,CI.I,''))))V(EventName,EventValue)
         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(V.EventValue,'->','|'),'|',1) SS
    GROUP BY P.EventTime,
             P.item,
             V.EventName) --Will also need to group on a unique value if this is coming from a table, not a variable
SELECT R.EventName,
       R.ToValue
FROM RNs R
WHERE R.RN = 1;

But, of course, as I stated in the comments, data like you have here should never be getting to the database. Fix the design; don't store your data like this. As you have found, working with it is a pain... As a temporary solution, you could use a VIEW, but the long term goal should be fixing things. Future you will thank you.

I am getting the following error: Procedure or function STRING_SPLIT has too many arguments specified.  This is an interesting solution, taking the string a putting it into a table then pulling the last 'row'.  I agree this isn't ideal but fixing the DB isn't an option for me.

@PurpleHaze - what's your version and compatibility level?

Considering you are on 16.0.1000.6, you have access to that feature, @PurpleHaze . What compatilibity level is your database? Also, why have you not installed any security or bug fixes for 2 years..?

We actually have three different SQL Servers.  I don't have control over the updates/upgrades.  We have two ERP instances that use two different servers: one is SQL Server 15.0.4355.3, the other is 12.0.6449.1. I am actually set up on a different server: 16.0.1000.6 and access these other two via linked servers.  I know...it's crazy..again, out of my control.  So this solution will need to be able to work on both ERP servers. I'm not sure how to answer the compatibility question.

So you aren't using SQL Server 2022 really, @PurpleHaze ? Then you'll need to use a different (user-defined inline table type) function, such as DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD.

12.0.6449.1 is also end of life. It is, however, at least the last version of SQL Server 2014 that was released (so patched, unlike your 2022 server), but you do need to urgently upgrade that server as much as you need to update your 2022 server.

I know, I know.  Please don't beat me up over the servers we have.  Again, I have no control over upgrades, updates, or versions.  The people in charge of those are aware.  I'm not sure what the issues are that they haven't been upgrated.

So the error I encountered was because I was connected to the wrong server.  I am able to run it on 16.0.1000.6.

String parsing does not seem to me to be a very promising approach, since the number of logging values is practically unlimited. I suggest you look at the query option using STRIG_SPLIT, if this is applicable in your version of SQL Server.
Your log entry has a clear structure.



idx
part




1
12:01:07


2
OnHandQty:


3
10000.00000000


4
->


5
9743.00000000



We can use string_split to split the entire string into parts (removing extra spaces). Next, combine into a group of 5 parts, put them back together.
See example
DECLARE @inputString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '12:01:07  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  12:01:07  OnHandQty: 9743.00000000 -> 10000.00000000  15:24:25  DemandQty: 0 -> 257.00000000  15:31:09  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  15:31:09  DemandQty: 257.00000000 -> 127.00000000'
Declare @searchName NVARCHAR(100)='DemandQty';

select oldValue,newValue
from(
select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by logname order by logtime )rn
from(
  select grp
    ,max(case when idxn=1 then cast(part as time) end) logtime
    ,max(case when idxn=2 then left(part,len(part)-1) end) logName
    ,max(case when idxn=3 then part end) oldValue
    ,max(case when idxn=0 then part end) newValue
  from(
     select s.ordinal as idx, value as part 
       ,(ordinal+4)/5 as grp
       ,ordinal%5 as idxn
     from string_split(replace(@inputString,'  ',' '),' ',1)s
   )a
   group by grp
 )b
)c
where logName=@searchName and rn=1 





oldValue
newValue




0
257.00000000



fiddle
And query parsing all rows from table
create table test (id int, logstring varchar(max));
insert into test values
 (1,'12:01:07  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  12:01:07  OnHandQty: 9743.00000000 -> 10000.00000000  15:24:25  DemandQty: 0 -> 257.00000000  15:31:09  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  15:31:09  DemandQty: 257.00000000 -> 127.00000000')
;

select *
from(
select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by id,logname order by logtime )rn
from(
select id,grp
  ,max(case when idxn=1 then cast(part as time) end) logtime
  ,max(case when idxn=2 then left(part,len(part)-1) end) logName
  ,max(case when idxn=3 then part end) oldValue
  ,max(case when idxn=0 then part end) newValue
from(
select t.id,s.ordinal as idx, value as part 
  ,(ordinal+4)/5 as grp
  ,ordinal%5 as idxn
from test t
cross apply(select * from string_split(replace(logstring,'  ',' '),' ',1))s
)a
group by id,grp
)b
)c
where rn=1




id
grp
logtime
logName
oldValue
newValue
rn




1
3
15:24:25.0000000
DemandQty
0
257.00000000
1


1
1
12:01:07.0000000
OnHandQty
10000.00000000
9743.00000000
1



Before grouping we have

string parts (5 for every log),
grp - this is number of update
idxn - number of part in grp

Table 2.



id
idx
part
grp
idxn




1
1
12:01:07
1
1


1
2
OnHandQty:
1
2


1
3
10000.00000000
1
3


1
4
->
1
4


1
5
9743.00000000
1
0


1
6
12:01:07
2
1


1
7
OnHandQty:
2
2


1
8
9743.00000000
2
3


1
9
->
2
4


1
10
10000.00000000
2
0


1
11
15:24:25
3
1


1
12
DemandQty:
3
2


1
13
0
3
3


1
14
->
3
4


1
15
257.00000000
3
0


1
16
15:31:09
4
1


1
17
OnHandQty:
4
2


1
18
10000.00000000
4
3


1
19
->
4
4


1
20
9743.00000000
4
0


1
21
15:31:09
5
1


1
22
DemandQty:
5
2


1
23
257.00000000
5
3


1
24
->
5
4


1
25
127.00000000
5
0



fiddle

For SQL Server version without STRING_SPLIT
DECLARE @inputString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '12:01:07  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  12:01:07  OnHandQty: 9743.00000000 -> 10000.00000000  15:24:25  DemandQty: 0 -> 257.00000000  15:31:09  OnHandQty: 10000.00000000 -> 9743.00000000  15:31:09  DemandQty: 257.00000000 -> 127.00000000'
Declare @SearchName NVARCHAR(100)='DemandQty';

select substring(s1,1,charindex(':',s1)-1) sName
  ,substring(s1,charindex(':',s1)+len('->'),charindex('->',s1)-1-charindex(':',s1)-2)fromValue
  ,substring(s1,charindex('->',s1)++len('->')+1
        ,case when charindex(' ',s1,charindex('->',s1)+len('->')+1)>0 then
           charindex(' ',s1,charindex('->',s1)+len('->')+1)-charindex('->',s1)-2
         else len(s1) end
        ) toValue
from(
select 
  case when charindex(@SearchName+':',s0)>0 then
    substring(s0
   ,len(s0)-charindex(':'+reverse(@SearchName),reverse(s0))-len(@SearchName)+1
   ,len(s0)) 
  end s1
  from (select trim(replace(@inputString,'  ',' ')) s0)a
)b




sName
fromValue
toValue




DemandQty
257.00000000
127.00000000



fiddle
